# Как защитить авторизационные куки от кражи? Как защита устроена в VK, OK и проч?

Tags: php, cookie, браузер, защита, пароль

Всем привет!
Как сделать так, чтобы куки с хэшированным паролем и id пользователя не могли быть получены другим сайтом, кроме моего?

Сейчас защита на сайте ломается в два этапа:
1. Я авторизуюсь как пользователь и захожу с браузера на свой сайт, он мне кидает запрос на куки с хэшированным паролем и id - они запрашиваются каждый раз и сверяются при каком-либо ответственном действии на сайте.
2. Я этот запрос сохраняю, затем создаю серый ресурс, который кидается скопированным запросом.
И проблема такая, что когда я захожу на серый ресурс(случайно или умышленно) - браузер получает скопированный запрос и отправляет куки, сохраненные для белого сайта XD
В итоге пока хэшированные значения не изменились - теоретически я могу зайти с другого браузера с этими значениями вместо другого пользователя, которого я "взломал"

Подскажите - как разобраться( и как грамотные люди разбираются с этой проблемой? )

P.S. с ресурсами типа vk.com ok.ru avito.ru и прочими крупными соц сетями такой фокус не работает?

Можно ли ограничить отправку куков по домену?

И как вам решение менять и перезаписывать хэшированные значения каждый раз при совершении действия на сайте, которое требует ввода этих значений?

Всем спасибо!

Comment: В куках не должно быть ни id, ни тем более пароля, даже хэшированных

Comment: Cookie это просто ключ, выданный вам сервером, по которому на каждый ваш запрос он делает аутентификацию - проверку на соответствие этого ключа тем параметрам как он был выдан - как то User-agent,  IP адрес, и много что ещё в принципе. Как уже было сказано печенька это не просто хеш пароля которая проверяется при тупом копировании.

Comment: Ребята, спустя два года участия в нескольких проектах и самостоятельно написанных приложений - я спрашивал про csrf-атаки))) Не стал специально редактировать вопрос - это пример того как его может задать новичок столкнувшись с кросс-браузерной подделкой запроса. Решается вопрос просто - к сессии добавляется csrf-токен, который каждый раз отправляется с запросом сервера для проверки - с той страницы пришел запрос или нет.

Answer (score 1):

В куках нельзя сохранять хеш пароля или id - это очень небезопасно. Это будет так же глупо, как сделать куку `id_admin=true`. Кто-либо сможет обойти такое.

Принято использовать сессии.
Все нужные данные сохраняются на сервере, а клиенту выдается идентификатор сессии. Подробнее можно почитать в [справочнике PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.session.php). Идентификатор должен быть длинным и случайным, чтоб его невозможно было подобрать. В PHP это всё доступно из коробки.

На сервере вы можете что-либо сохранять в сессию. Данные будут привязаны к клиенту с помощью идентификатора сессии, но сами данные на клиенте находится не будут.
Обычно в сессии сохраняют id залогиненого пользователя. Для защиты от кражи кук так же можно сохранять User-Agent браузера и IP.

Так же кукам нужно настроить правильные пути, домены, атрибуты `secure` и `httponly`.

Так же эта тема довольно хорошо описана [на Хабре](https://habr.com/ru/post/437972/), советую взглянуть.

Comment: Вчитался в вопрос и подумал, может неправильно вас понял. Наверное вам нужна защита от CSRF-атак, верно?

Comment: Добрый день! Да! Извиняюсь за долгий ответ. Уже разобрался сам - на тот момент, когда задавался вопрос - я не конца понимал о чем спрашивал. И меня просто поражало как сторонний сайт может выполнить действие от имени пользователя(например завершить сессию), хотя браузер не отдает ему куки. Сейчас я знаю, что такое csrf-token и как его использовать)))

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что подозрительные ссылки в вк блокируются и пользователь попадает на страницу с предупреждением. Вк вообще не дает переходить на внешние подозрительные сайты (триггерит например на большинство .tk домены), но можно на этой странице устроить очищение хэша перед переходом.